# i am using open CV and i am facing this error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,frameWidth)
cap.set(4,frameHeight)
cap.set(10,150)

myColors=[[5,107,0,19,255,255],
         [133,56,0,159,156.255],
         [57,76,0,100,255,255]]

def findColors(img,myColors):
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    for color in myColors:
        lower =  np.array(color[0:3])
        upper =  np.array(color[3:6])
        mask  = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)
        cv2.imshow(str(color[0]),mask)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    findColors(img,myColors)
    cv2.imshow("result", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord ('q'):
        break
```

I have been trying to create a color tracker which would go about tracing the color from the camera.

```
error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The upper boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function 'cv::inRange'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is a typo in your code.

```
[133,56,0,159,156.255],
```

use a `,` there, not a `.`

Comment: According to [help/on-topic] "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error." are off topic. Such problems (and associated solutions) are considered not useful for a wider audience, and as such should be closed and not answered (a comment explaining the mistake is sufficient to help the asker). The tooltip for the downvote button says "This answer is not useful".